# concurrent exception in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3, but my build.gradle file is generating a time face concurrent exception. I don't understand why this exception is thrown.

[image: Error and gradle are display .]

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Error:com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error:Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 6.511 secs
>   Information:6 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kbook"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    //compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you made any nine ppatch image youself?

Comment: why are you excluding android support packages?

Comment: Thank u but I have not use any image only default image "ic_launcher" .

Comment: i have post full log .

Comment: testing purpose .

Comment: @Kuldeep  whats the format of that testing file .png?

Comment: why u down vote for this question?

Comment: @Kuldeep not me but probably because less  descriptive

Comment: I am not using testing file.png where u see .

Comment: @Kuldeep file > invalidate cache & restart > and run again

Comment: ok i will try it ...

Comment: i will try but it not work same exception are throw again .

Comment: what did you comment  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'` any reason?

Comment: find some solution that time some one is tell me to comment it and work proper but it not work .\

Comment: you should use that `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` add this sync and run if its not installed run with the one you have latest one is 25.1.1 thaugh

Comment: Post your full app:gradle

Comment: already try but it not work .

Comment: ok check edit and post my gradle .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134546/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-charuka).